# first part of text is hidden in a select menu

Tags: html, css

Im using select2 for a select menu. It is working fine the issue is that when some text is written in the select menu the first part of the text is not visibile. Do you know how to fix that?

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/v4jqhh0m/1/)

html:

```
<form method="post" class="clearfix">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
      <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Options</label>
      <select id="list" multiple class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should remove the padding: 0.2rem 0.7rem;